# How to loop through each possible value matchup (two columns) and perform calculation? (College Football Related)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created a procedure that predicts College football game lines by using the variables @Team1 and @Team2.  In the current setup, these teams are entered manually.

**For example:**  `@Team1 = 'Ohio St.', @Team2 = 'Southern Miss.'`
Then, my calculation will go through a series of calculations on stats comparisons, strength of schedule, etc. to calculate the hypothetical game line (in this case, `Ohio St. -39`.)

Here's where I need your help:  I'm trying to turn this line prediction system into a ranking system, ranking each team from greatest to worst.  I'd like to take each team in my Team table and put it through this calculation with each possible matchup.  Then, rank the teams based on who has the biggest advantage over every team that given week, vs. who has the least advantage.

Any ideas?  I've toyed around with the idea of turning the calculation into a function and pass the values through that way, but not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are doing the calculation in SQL I would just make it a stored procedure.  Then you can just loop through the teams call the stored procedure pass the team names and then store the returned calculation in a table.  Then you can use the table of results to design your ranking

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the made-up column names, but the following should do what you want if you convert your proc to a function that takes the two team names as arguments:

```
Select a.Name as Team1
  , b.Name as Team2
  , fn_GetStats(a.Name, b.Name)
from TeamsList a
inner join TeamsList b
  on a.Name > b.Name --To avoid duplicate rows
order by 3 desc
```

The join will create a list of all possible unique combinations (e.g. TeamB and TeamA, but not also TeamA and TeamB or TeamA and TeamA).

Assuming the proc outputs just a single value right now, this seems like the easiest solution.  You could also do the same join and then loop through your proc with the results, instead.